# What caused the village drought in Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom?

Tags: indiana-jones, the-temple-of-doom

In Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom, Indiana ends up in Mayapore, a village in India, where a drought struck after their sacred stone was stolen and their children were stolen. The villagers believe that the drought is caused by the theft of the stone; however, the Thuggee cult seemed to have stored up a large reservoir of water, possibly implying that the water had simply been blocked off for their purposes, possibly as secondary blackmail to force the villagers to join them or convince them of their power.

The main problems with this are that if they needed to use the water and that is why they blocked it, there's not much reason to wait until they have the stone, besides convincing the villagers that there was a connection, and that the reservoir does not seem to be that large, nor is it made apparent from whence it flows. Furthermore, mystical powers are shown to be at work throughout the film, including curses, and the stone itself is shown to have powers of its own at the end when it burns High Priest Mola Ram, causing him to fall to his death, and not Indiana.

What is the official cause of the wells and rivers of the village running dry?

Comment: I'd guess lack of rainfall.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Magic.

Seriously, it is magic, the Indiana Jones world is one in which magic exists and works. Otherwise we'd have to ask questions like 'why do the bad guys faces melt?' and 'how did Indy get the Shankara stones to glow red hot by chanting?'.

Real world physics and reason takes a back seat to magic in the world of Indiana Jones. There's no connection between the big vat of water in the tunnels and the wells drying up, the reason the wells and fields dried up is because the magic stones were stolen.

Comment: Don't forget "How did the knight live so long?"